# protobuf-net serialize/deserialize DateTime & Guid types

Tags: java, c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have some issue with getting values from *TimeDate* and *Guid* types from *protobuf-net*:

I have *.Net Client* and *.Net Server* and they are communicating via *protobuf-net*. And now I have to implement a communication from a java client to this *.Net Server* and I can not change already existed *.Net Server* communication logic so I have to use already existed protobuf communication and the issue is following:

*protobuf-net* understands two *.net* types: *DateTime* and *Guid* but I'm not able to parse it via *google protobuf*:

.Net Server class example:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class SomeClass
{
[ProtoMember(1)]
public DateTime? CurrentDateTime { get; set; }

[ProtoMember(2)]
public Guid CurrentGiud { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not able to parse it via *google protobuf* because it knows nothing about *DateTime* and *Guid* types so I can only get *byte[]* from these fields, *.proto* example:

```
message SomeClass
{
 bytes CurrentDateTime = 1;
 bytes CurrentGiud = 2;
}
```

So after serialization/deserialization a stream I can get *byte[]* from those fields and now I need somehow convert it to appropriate values, so I need something like this:

```cs
var customDateTime = ConvertByteArrayToCustomDateTime(byteArray);
byte[] byteArray = ConvertCustomDateTimeToByteArray(customDateTime);

var customGuid = ConvertByteArrayToCustomGuid(byteArray);
byte[] byteArray = ConvertCustomGuidToByteArray(customGuid);
```

or this:

```cs
string strDateTime = ConvertByteArrayToStringDateTime(byteArray); //e.g. "13.08.2019 17:42:31"
byte[] byteArray = ConvertStringDateTimeToByteArray(strDateTime);

string strGuid = ConvertByteArrayToStringGuid(byteArray); // e.g. "{7bb7cdac-ebad-4acf-90ff-a5525be3caac}"
byte[] byteArray = ConvertStringGuidToByteArray(strGuid);
```

**DateTime real example:**

Example N1:

```
DateTime = 13.08.2019 17:42:31
after serialization/deserialization
byte[] = { 8, 142, 218, 151, 213, 11, 16, 3 }
```

Example N2:

```
DateTime = 25.06.2019 20:15:10
after serialization/deserialization
byte[] = { 8, 156, 131, 148, 209, 11, 16, 3 }
```

**Guid real example:**

Example N1:

```
Guid = {7bb7cdac-ebad-4acf-90ff-a5525be3caac}
after serialization/deserialization
byte[] = { 9, 172, 205, 183, 123, 173, 235, 207, 74, 17, 144, 255, 165, 82, 91, 227, 202, 172 }
```

Example N2:

```
Guid = {900246bb-3a7b-44d4-9b2f-1da035ca51f4}
after serialization/deserialization
byte[] = { 9, 187, 70, 2, 144, 123, 58, 212, 68, 17, 155, 47, 29, 160, 53, 202, 81, 244 }
```

---

## Solution:

Add following messages into your *.proto*:

```
message CustomDateTime 
{
  sint64 value = 1; // the offset (in units of the selected scale) from 1970/01/01
  CustomTimeSpanScale scale = 2; // the scale of the timespan [default = DAYS]
  CustomDateTimeKind kind = 3; // the kind of date/time being represented [default = UNSPECIFIED]
  enum CustomTimeSpanScale 
  {
    DAYS = 0;
    HOURS = 1;
    MINUTES = 2;
    SECONDS = 3;
    MILLISECONDS = 4;
    TICKS = 5;

    MINMAX = 15; // dubious
  }
  enum CustomDateTimeKind
  {     
     // The time represented is not specified as either local time or Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).
     UNSPECIFIED = 0;
     // The time represented is UTC.
     UTC = 1;
     // The time represented is local time.
     LOCAL = 2;
   }
}

message CustomGuid 
{
  fixed64 lo = 1; // the first 8 bytes of the guid (note:crazy-endian)
  fixed64 hi = 2; // the second 8 bytes of the guid (note:crazy-endian)
}
```

Now your *.proto* class should look like this:

```
message SomeClass
{
 CustomDateTime CurrentDateTime = 1;
 CustomGuid CurrentGiud = 2;
}
```

**Simple *DateTime* parser:**

```
        public static string ConvertCustomDateTimeToString(CustomDateTime customDateTime)
        {
            var dateTime = DateTime.Parse("01.01.1970 00:00:00");

            if (customDateTime.Scale == CustomDateTime.Types.CustomTimeSpanScale.Seconds)
            {
                dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(customDateTime.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("CustomDateTime supports only seconds");
            }

            return dateTime.ToString();
        }

        public static CustomDateTime ConvertStringToCustomDateTime(string strDateTime)
        {
            var defaultTime = DateTime.Parse("01.01.1970 00:00:00");
            var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(strDateTime);

            var customDateTime = new CustomDateTime
            {
                Kind = CustomDateTime.Types.CustomDateTimeKind.Unspecified,
                Scale = CustomDateTime.Types.CustomTimeSpanScale.Seconds,
                Value = (long) (dateTime - defaultTime).TotalSeconds
            };

            return customDateTime;
        }
```

**Simple *Guid* parser:**

```
public static string ConvertCustomGuidToString(CustomGuid customGuid)
        {
            var str = string.Empty;

            var array = BitConverter.GetBytes(customGuid.Lo);

            var newArray = new byte[8];
            newArray[0] = array[3];
            newArray[1] = array[2];
            newArray[2] = array[1];
            newArray[3] = array[0];
            newArray[4] = array[5];
            newArray[5] = array[4];
            newArray[6] = array[7];
            newArray[7] = array[6];

            str += BitConverter.ToString(newArray).Replace("-", "");

            str += BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(customGuid.Hi)).Replace("-", "");

            return str;
        }

        public static CustomGuid ConvertStringToCustomGuid(string strGuid)
        {
            strGuid = strGuid.Replace(" ", "");
            strGuid = strGuid.Replace("-", "");
            strGuid = strGuid.Replace("{", "");
            strGuid = strGuid.Replace("}", "");

            if (strGuid.Length != 32)
            {
                throw new Exception("Wrong Guid format");
            }

            byte[] array = new byte[16];

            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i += 2)
                array[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(strGuid.Substring(i, 2), 16);

            var newArrayLo = new byte[8];
            newArrayLo[0] = array[3];
            newArrayLo[1] = array[2];
            newArrayLo[2] = array[1];
            newArrayLo[3] = array[0];
            newArrayLo[4] = array[5];
            newArrayLo[5] = array[4];
            newArrayLo[6] = array[7];
            newArrayLo[7] = array[6];

            var newArrayHi = new byte[8];
            newArrayHi[0] = array[8];
            newArrayHi[1] = array[9];
            newArrayHi[2] = array[10];
            newArrayHi[3] = array[11];
            newArrayHi[4] = array[12];
            newArrayHi[5] = array[13];
            newArrayHi[6] = array[14];
            newArrayHi[7] = array[15];

            var customGuid = new CustomGuid
            {
                Lo = BitConverter.ToUInt64(newArrayLo, 0),
                Hi = BitConverter.ToUInt64(newArrayHi, 0)
            };

            return customGuid;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to talk about the two types separately. There's back-story to each!

---

`DateTime` / `TimeSpan` - so: *way back* in history, .NET folks kept wanting protobuf-net to round-trip `DateTime` / `TimeSpan`. There was nothing defined by Google for this kind of purpose, so protobuf-net *made something up*. The details are in [bcl.proto](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/master/src/Tools/bcl.proto), but I don't recommend worrying about that. The short version would be: "they're kinda awkward to work with if you're not protobuf-net".

Roll forward 5+ years, and Google *finally* defined the well-known `Duration` and `Timestamp` types. Unfortunately, they're not 1:1 matches for how protobuf-net decided to implement them, and I can't change the default layout without breaking existing consumers. But! For new code, or for cross-platform purposes, protobuf-net *knows how to talk `Duration` / `Timestamp`*, and if it is *even remotely possible*, I **strongly** recommend changing your layout. The good news is: this is really simple:

```cs
[ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.WellKnown)]
public DateTime? CurrentDateTime { get; set; }
```

This will now use `.google.protobuf.Timestamp` instead of `.bcl.DateTime`; this also works with `TimeSpan` / `.google.protobuf.Duration`.

The key point here: there is a simple option that you can switch to that will make this "just work"; the default is for compatibility with something that protobuf-net had to invent before Google had decided on a layout.

Note that changing to `DataFormat.WellKnown` is a data breaking change; the layout is **different**. If there was a way to automatically detect and compensate, it already would; there isn't.

---

`Guid` - this *should* have been much simpler; the sensible idea here would have been to just to serialize it as `bytes` in .proto terms, but ... and I regret this, I did a stupid and tried to do something clever. It backfired and I regret it. What it does is ... kinda silly, although it does make sense internally. It accesses the `Guid` as two consecutive `fixed64` fields (again, look in `bcl.proto`) where these are the low/high bytes *in Microsoft's craz-endian layout*. By crazy-endian, I mean where the guid `00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF` is represented by the bytes `33-22-11-00-55-44-77-66-88-99-AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF` (emphasis: this bit isn't me; this is what Microsoft and .NET do internally with guids). So; to take your N1 example, the two half fragments you're seeing there are:

- 0x09 = "field 1, type fixed64"
- 0x AC-CD-B7-7B-AD-EB-CF-4A - first half in crazy-endian
- 0x11 (decimal 17) = "field 2, type fixed64"
- 0x 90-FF-A5-52-5B-E3-CA-AC - second half in crazy-endian

Frankly, for cross-platform work, I would suggest for `Guid`, expose it as `string` or `byte[]` instead, and accept my sincere apologies for the inconvenience!

---

In both cases: if you can't change the layout, look in bcl.proto for what is actually happening. If you use `Serializer.GetProto<T>()`, it should generate a schema that imports bcl.proto automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not touch existing logic, so I cannot change *DataFormat* to *DataFormat.WellKnown*, communication format should remain. I just used *bcl.proto* and added custom logic to parse it and it works, thanks a lot! you've saved my day!

Comment: Are there any changes to this as of protobuf-net 3.x?

Comment: @BryanRayner the "well known" concept has been expanded into "compatibility level" (https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net/compatibilitylevel.html)